# Model pre-preenchida retorna nula no HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou construindo uma pagina no projeto ASP.NET onde tenho um model que contem 2 listas, que preencho uma inicialmente no get e depois direciono para a View onde preencho outra lista, porem ao receber esse objeto, ele me retorna com todos os dados em nulo, nem os dados iniciais que preenchi ele vem.

ViewModel

```
public class ChamadoAvaliacaoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Assunto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Responsavel do Chamado")]
    public ApplicationUser ResponsavelChamado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Solução")]
    public string Solucao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Avaliação do Chamado")]
    public int AvaliacaoChamado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Justificativa da Avaliação")]
    public string JustificativaAvaliacao { get; set; }
    public List<ChamadoTipoAvaliacao> ChamadoTiposAvaliacao { get; set; }
    public List<ChamadoAvaliacao> ChamadoAvaliacao { get; set; }
}
```

Actions

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AvaliacaoChamado(string id)
    {
        var chamado = new ChamadoDAO(db).BuscarChamadoId(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        if (chamado.StatusChamado.Value)
        {
            var model = new ChamadoAvaliacaoViewModel();
            model.Id = chamado.Id;
            model.Descricao = chamado.Descricao;
            model.Assunto = chamado.Assunto;
            model.Solucao = chamado.Solucao;
            model.ResponsavelChamado = chamado.ResponsavelChamado;
            model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao = new ChamadoTipoAvaliacaoGN(db).retornarChamadoTipoAvaliacao();
            model.ChamadoAvaliacao = new List<ChamadoAvaliacao>();
            foreach (var ChamadoTipoAvaliacao in model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao)
            {
                model.ChamadoAvaliacao.Add(new ChamadoAvaliacao());
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["notice"] = "Chamado não pode ser avaliado, pois ele não foi encerrado.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Chamado");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AvaliacaoChamado(string id, ChamadoAvaliacaoViewModel chamadoAvaliacao)
    {
        var aGN = new ChamadoAvaliacaoGN(db);
        var cGN = new ChamadoGN(db);
        var chamado = new ChamadoDAO(db).BuscarChamadoId(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        foreach (var avaliacao in chamadoAvaliacao.ChamadoAvaliacao)
        {
            aGN.registrarAvaliacao(avaliacao);
        }
        cGN.RegistrarUltimaInteracao(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        TempData["notice"] = "Chamado Avaliado com Sucesso!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao[i].Id == 1)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao[i].Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ChamadoAvaliacao[i].Justificativa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", Style = "height:130px" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChamadoAvaliacao[i].Justificativa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacao[i].Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ChamadoAvaliacao[i].Nota, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "rating rating-loading AvaliacaoChamado" })                        
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChamadoAvaliacao[i].Nota, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    }
```

Comment: Já tive um problema semelhante, fiz dar o post via javascript mesmo, pelo ajax...

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni estou pesquisando o ciclo de vida do model na view, pois não sei se ele invalida logo após a renderização da pagina ou mantem até o post, se ele invalida logo na renderização qualquer post não vai adiantar...

Answer (score 0):

No essencial, tipos de dados primitivos TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, Decimal, String, etc são bem "percebidos" pelo ModelBinding. 
O que pretendes é fazer POST ao controlador e passar um tipo de dados complexo sendo que este também contem variáveis de tipo complexo.

```
public class ChamadoAvaliacaoViewModel
```

contem

```
public List<ChamadoTipoAvaliacao> ChamadoTiposAvaliacao { get; set; }
public List<ChamadoAvaliacao> ChamadoAvaliacao { get; set; }
```

Tens duas soluções:

A primeira é hardcode html que contenha Id´s e Names de acordo com as List.

A segunda é ter na ViewModel um array para cada lista de forma a que o Binding seja efetuado:

```
public class ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoViewModel{

public List<ChamadoTiposAvaliacao> ChamadoTiposAvaliacao{ get; set; }
public ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoPostViewModel[] ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoArray { get; set; }}
```

View da segunda opção

```
@for (var itemCnt = 0; itemCnt < Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoArray.Count(); itemCnt++){
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoArray[itemCnt].campo1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoArray[itemCnt].campo2)
</td></tr>}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AlgumaPostAction(int id, ChamadoTiposAvaliacaoViewModel model)
{
    //...
```